# How to make Angular `routerLink` fragment navigation scroll to my `id` target?

Tags: angular, scroll, navigation, routerlink, angular-routerlink

Can someone please help me to get the `routerLink` fragment scroll to work?

=> *"Working" meaning that when I click on the routerLink, it does scroll to the element with the matching id.* ;)

Code example of what I did:

```html
<co-trigger routerLink="." [fragment]="item?.id" *ngFor="let item of items">Trigger</co-trigger>
...
<co-target [attr.id]="item?.id" *ngFor="let item of items">Target</co-target>
```

Notes:

- Both the `co-trigger` and the `co-target` are in the same template.
- Some `co-target` instances have enough content so that there is a scroll bar to make it meaningful to scroll to that item by clicking on the trigger.
- The url in the navigation bar changes as expected `url#item-id`, however no scroll happens when clicking on the trigger.

My `AppRoutingModule` setup:

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      routes,
      {
        onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
        scrollOffset: [0, 64], // [x, y] - adjust scroll offset
      }
    ),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Context information:

```
Angular: 11.2.6
```

Any ideas on what I can do to get the "*scroll to anchor target*" functionality to work?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I use a package named [ngx-page-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

**Step 1**

So each element you can define a method called scroll like this :

**app.component.html**

```
<a class="nav-link" (click)="scroll(home)">Link Name</a>
```

**Step 2**

In the same component **app.component.html** define your section with an **ID** **#home** like this :

```
<section #home>
...
</section>
```

**Step 3**

Now in the **app.component.ts** you can implement the scroll method like this :

```
scroll(el: HTMLElement) {

  el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

}
```